# Is there a way to fix this Mailchimp API error in node?

Tags: node.js, mailchimp

Is there a way to fix this MailChimp API error in Node.js?

```
{
  type: 'http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/',
  title: 'Invalid Resource',
  status: 400,
  detail: "The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.",
  instance: '95a2824e-4f30-4ce4-8c5e-322859d933e4',
  errors: [
    {
      field: 'members.item:0.status',
      message: 'Data presented is not one of the accepted values: subscribed, unsubscribed, cleaned, pending.'
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the API call the Node app is trying to do? Looks like its trying to add a member to a list, so assuming you are making this request `POST /lists/{list_id}/members`

The required fields in the body needs to be:

```
{
    "email_address": "",
    "status": ""
}
```

Based on the error message, you are not passing in a status in the POST request. Possible values are the following: "subscribed", "unsubscribed", "cleaned", "pending", or "transactional".