# Can't figure out why I am getting this error in my terminal while creating a webpage with the help of API

Tags: javascript

This is my javascript code . while I am running it using nodemon I am getting error in my terminal . The error is mentioned at the bottom of the code

```
const express=require("express");
const bodypraser=require("body-parser");
const request =require("request");
const https=require("https");


const app=express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodypraser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
```

posting from route

```
 app.post("/",function(req,res)
{
const firstname=req.body.fname;
 const lastname=req.body.lname;
const email=req.body.email;
const data={
members:[
{
email_address:email,
status:"suscribed",
merge_fields:{
  FNAME:firstname,
  LNAME:lastname
  }
}
]};

const jsondata=JSON.stringify(data);
const url= "https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/a6b99f4c3c";
```

creating option object

```
const options={
method:"POST",
auth:"deco:d6550609e1d79db44b409d81841d74bf-us1"
 }
const request=https.request(url,options,function(response){
 response.on("data",function(data){
console.log(JSON.parse(data));
})
 })

request.write(jsondata);
request.end();

});

app.get("/" ,function(req ,res){
res.sendFile(__dirname+"/signup.html");
});
app.listen(3000,function(req,res){
console.log("ok ");
});
```

End of code

[This is the error which I am facing in my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smj22.png)

```
{
 type: 'https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/errors/',
 title: 'Invalid Resource',
```

This is the error status

```
 status: 400,
 detail: "The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific 
 details, see the 'errors' array.",
 instance: '26cacd7a-d1b6-4195-9407-9eb39a9ec224',
  errors: [
  {
  field: 'members.item:0.status',
  message: 'Data presented is not one of the accepted values: subscribed, 
  unsubscribed, cleaned, pending.'
  }
]
}
```

Comment: copy paste the error message - pictures of errors are messy to deal with if we want to search for similar errors for you - seems [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65811569/is-there-a-way-to-fix-this-mailchimp-api-error-in-node) may help - maybe

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message. Mailchimp requires `status` to be one of the four values mentioned in the error. Your status has two typos (status:"Suscribed") instead of subscribed (note the case sensitivity).

Next time you post a question please use proper [code indentation](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse154/18au/resources/styleguide/js/spacing-indentation-js.html).